# What happened to the "history" and "timeline" links on questions?

Tags: support

In the course of  this year I found two new links below questions

- history
- timeline

Although I know I can access both via other paths (history: via the "edited" link, timeline: https://askubuntu.com/posts/#####/timeline)
I found the explicit links useful.

Why don't I see them any more?

Comment: I don't remember ever seeing such links. Did you have a userscript that added them, that was broken by the Firefox 57 update?

Comment: Maybe you had this script here? https://stackapps.com/questions/2047/add-timeline-and-revisions-links

Comment: @Zanna amazing how well you know me :-)

Answer (score 10):

Well as @Zanna had said, there never existed such links natively, but I was using this fine userscript
[SE Modifications](https://stackapps.com/questions/2138/se-modifications-username-autocomplete-in-comments-inline-revision-source-a)
which is apparently broken (at least in my installation) right now.

Before switching to tampermonkey I was looking for an easy way to transfer the userscripts and stumbled over
[Userscript works in Tampermonkey on Chrome but not in Greasemonkey on Firefox (Stack Overflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32957523/userscript-works-in-tampermonkey-on-chrome-but-not-in-greasemonkey-on-firefox), where I found

> Add before // ==/UserScript== on a new line:
>   // @grant          GM_addStyle

Thats all that was needed (strange how it worked until now...)

Comment: Of you olwb the browser console on a question what do you see?

Comment: @Seth valuable hint, I get `Failed checking whether [Greasemonkey Script github.com/SE Modifications] runs at "..." : TypeError: matchPattern.doMatch is not a function`, accompanied by a stack trace.

Comment: `matchPattern.doMatch` doesn't appear in the code anywhere, which makes me think this is a bug in greasemonkey and not the script. Try installing the tampermonkey plugin for firefox and using that for the script.

Comment: @Seth great suggestion - with tampermonkey the links are back :-)